# matlab: add a row of zeros at specific row numbers

Tags: matlab, insert, rows, zero

Wanted to ask help on the following: I have a dataset 131573*8 and I would like to add 19247*8 zero-rows to the dataset. The zero rows need to be added at specific places, which I have stored in a matrix YE, which is of size: 19247*1.

To give an example:
The first element of YE is the number 56. For that specific row I would like to add a row of zeros in the matrix dataset.
Now dataset row 55-57 looks something like:

55: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

56: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

57: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38

It should be:

55: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

56: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

57: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

58: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38

I hope someone can help me - I have not found any solution yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *insert* rows of zeroes into `dataset` at specific row indices, one vectorized way is to initialize a matrix of zeroes of your desired final size, then fill the rows that *aren't* in your index vector `YE` with the contents of `dataset`:

```
N = size(dataset, 1)+size(YE, 1);
result = zeros(N, size(dataset, 2));
result(setdiff(1:N, YE), :) = dataset;
```

However, the above solution creates a *new* matrix `result`, which uses more memory. If you'd like to modify `dataset` directly and save on memory (since it's a large matrix), here's an alternative:

```
% Add the necessary number of rows of zeroes to the end:
dataset = [dataset; zeros([size(YE, 1) size(dataset, 2)])];

% Create an index vector to reorder the rows:
[~, index] = sort([setdiff(1:size(dataset, 1), YE).'; YE]);

% Reorder the rows:
dataset = dataset(index, :);
```

Comment: Hi gnovice, thank you for your fast reply! The solution does replace the row with zeros but it should add the row (as an extra row). I have updated the example as I think that better explains the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot gnovice, a very neat and useful solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use your index YE to set the rows to 0:

```
dataset(YE, :) = zeros(1, size(dataset,2));
```

Edit: I see you are trying to insert the zeros, rather than set that row equal to 0, so disregard the above.  I would recommend converting your logical index YE to row numbers and then operating as follows:

```
rowsYE = find(YE == 1);
for idx = 1:length(rowsYE)
    newData = dataset(1:rowsYE(idx)-1,:);  % temp variable to hold data
    newData(rowsYE(idx),:) = zeros(1,size(dataset,2)); % add a row of zeros
    newData = [newData; dataset(rowsYE(idx):end,:)]; % add the rest of the data set
    dataset = newData; % set the dataset = to temp 
    rowsYE = rowsYE + 1; % increment the rows index (since we added a new row)
end
```

Comment: Hi Joel, I see what you mean. This works to replace the row in dataset but I would like to add a 'new' row. Maybe the updated example clarifies the problem better?

Comment: Yeah I realized that after I wrote it, see my update.

Comment: Looking more closely, it looks like your index YE already includes row numbers?  If so, my solution above should work, just ignore the first line (rowsYE = find(YE == 1);

Comment: Thank you so much! (The YE indeed includes the row numbers)